# Making of setup files for php codes and sql database

Tags: php, sql

I have an phpmyadmin sql database which is controlled by some php files kept in c:/xampp/htdocs. Now I want to move the whole set up to another computer. An obvious way is to export import of the database and copy/paste of the php files. Is it possible to make a setup file so that when we run the setup file in some computer, the whole set up will be installed in that computer (as we install software)? 
Excuse me it is a foolish question.

Comment: Just export/import your MySQL database.  You would probably want a fresh install of PHPMyAdmin on the new server anyway as that server may have different software versions and such running.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, you should use **git** (http://git-scm.com/) for keeping your files the same and for version control.

With git you can easily clone the php files into your second computer.
You should also add *.log, *.lock, cache and user-data to your **.gitignore** file as well as various OS files (*.thumbs, *.DS_Store, etc.).

Getting an identical webserver up is more tricky tho... Here **Vagrant** (https://www.vagrantup.com/) can be of great use as it lets you "Create and configure lightweight, reproducible, and portable development environments."

For replicating databases, you can use vagrant too...

**Take a look at:** http://scotch.io/tutorials/get-vagrant-up-and-running-in-no-time

Comment: I'd like to add: don't forget to blacklist cache/log/userdata folders from using .gitignore